# Laravel doesn't work mutator for field in model pivot

Tags: php, laravel, mutators

I have two models linked by a pivot table. I want to make a mutator in the pivot table for the user_id field. My models

```
class User extends Model
{
     public function roles()
     {
        $this->belongsToMany(
            Role::class,
            'role_user',
            'user_id',
            'role_id'
        )->withPivot('status')->using(UserRole::class);
     }
}

class Role extends Model
{
     public function users()
     {
        $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class,
            'role_user',
            'role_id',
            'user_id'
        )->withPivot('status')->using(UserRole::class);
     }
}
```

My pivot table

```
class UserRole extends Pivot
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'role_id',
        'user_id',
        'status'
    ];
}
```

If I specify the mutator name

```
public function setStatusAttribute($value){
    dd("Hello");
}
```

it's work, but if I specify the mutator name

```
public function setUserIdAttribute($value){
    dd("Hello");
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to extend Pivot? You tried to extend UserRoles from Model?

Comment: Yes, I tried. The problem is that in a withPivot() relationship, it is not possible for the pivot model to be Model. As here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60335660/9584689

Comment: I made a mokup, and everything works fine. For eg. calling `$userRole = new UserRole(); $userRole->user_id = 100;`. The setUserIdAttribute() gets called. When is failing your code?